# How to find arm-apple-darwin#-llvm-gcc-4.2 compiler on Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, gcc, linker, xcode5, llvm-gcc

I am tying a cross compilation and for that I need to find where Xcode have placed the arm-gcc compiller.

It used to be in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 but it has vanished in Xcode 5.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the newer clang compiler instead like this: -

for CC:
xcrun -find -sdk iphoneos clang

for CXX:
xcrun -find -sdk iphoneos clang++

Comment: You where right. The platform I was trying to build is now using clang by default and it appears to work.
Thanks, Benny

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best to use `xcrun -find` to dynamically locate Xcode command-line tools for you, rather than explicitly using a path, since the path to Xcode tools may change over time. See `man xcrun` for details on how to use it, including details on the `-sdk iphoneos` flag you may need to pass to look for iOS tools.

If `xcrun` cannot locate the tool, it may no longer be included as part of Xcode. See the release notes for Xcode 5 to check if something has been officially removed.

Comment: It haven' t found any arm file =/

Comment: And have you checked the release notes for this Xcode version? See Apple's Developer website, near the link where you downloaded Xcode from, so view release notes. Its possible tools may have been removed or replaced with something different.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html

**Compiler**

```
**LLVM-GCC is not included in Xcode 5**
```

[image]