# Compile Poco Library for iPhone5S (arm64)

Tags: ios, openssl, poco-libraries, arm64

I want to compile the Poco Library for iPhone5S(arm64). However, I come across the following compile error.

Step to Do

> ./configure --config=iPhone -static --no-tests --no-samples --omit=Data/ODBC,Data/MySQL 
>   make IPHONE_SDK_VERSION_MIN=4.3 POCO_TARGET_OSARCH=arm64 -s -j4

And following error was found.

> /Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/build/script/makedepend.gcc src/LogFile.cpp /Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Foundation/.dep/iPhoneOS/arm64/LogFile.d /Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Foundation/obj/iPhoneOS/arm64/debug_static /Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Foundation/obj/iPhoneOS/arm64/release_static /Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Foundation/obj/iPhoneOS/arm64/debug_shared /Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Foundation/obj/iPhoneOS/arm64/release_shared  -Iinclude -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/CppUnit/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Foundation/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/XML/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Util/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Net/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Crypto/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/NetSSL_OpenSSL/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Data/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Data/SQLite/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Data/ODBC/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Data/MySQL/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/Zip/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/PageCompiler/include -I/Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/PageCompiler/File2Page/include -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -mthumb -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare  -DPOCO_BUILD_HOST=edric-macbook.local  -DPOCO_HAVE_IPv6 -DPOCO_NO_FPENVIRONMENT -DPOCO_NO_STAT64 -DPOCO_NO_SHAREDLIBS
>   ls: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-*: No such file or directory
>   /Users/edrictse/Downloads/poco-1.4.6p2-all/build/script/makedepend.gcc: line 24: -MM: command not found
>   ls: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-*: No such file or directory

Poco Library Version : poco-1.4.6p2
XCode Version : 5.0

Can anyone provide me the solution. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I come up with the solution which credit from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922885/how-to-find-arm-apple-darwin-llvm-gcc-4-2-compiler-on-xcode-5).

Step 1: Configure

> ./configure —config=iPhone —static —no-tests —no-samples --omit=Data/ODBC,Data/MySQL

For OpenSSL support

> ./configure —config=iPhone —static —no-tests —no-samples --omit=Data/ODBC,Data/MySQL --include-path=[OPENSSL INCLUDE PATH]

Step 2: Change the Compile

Open file in "poco-1.4.6p2-all/build/config/iPhone", Change :

- for CC: xcrun -find -sdk iphoneos clang
- for CXX: xcrun -find -sdk iphoneos clang++

Step 3: Make your library

- make IPHONE_SDK_VERSION_MIN=3.0 POCO_TARGET_OSARCH=armv6 -s -j4
- make IPHONE_SDK_VERSION_MIN=3.2 POCO_TARGET_OSARCH=armv7 -s -j4
- make IPHONE_SDK_VERSION_MIN=4.3 POCO_TARGET_OSARCH=armv7s -s -j4
- make IPHONE_SDK_VERSION_MIN=4.3 POCO_TARGET_OSARCH=arm64 -s -j4

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded poco library and was able to do the configure easily via:

```
[/tmp]:;./configure --config=iPhone -static --no-tests --no-samples --omit=Data/ODBC,Data/MySQL make IPHONE_SDK_VERSION_MIN=4.3 POCO_TARGET_OSARCH=arm64 -s -j4
Configured for iPhone
```

I suspect what you *really* need to do here is make certain your Xcode command line tools are installed. When you go to Xcode preferences, do you have them installed and set to the latest version, like this?

[image: Set Command Line Tools to latest version]

Command line tools (if you don't see them in that pop-up menu) can be downloaded from http://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: Michael, Thanks for your reply. I double check that Command Line tools is installed with XCode 5.0.1 version. However, the compile error is still exist. 

make IPHONE_SDK_VERSION_MIN=4.3 POCO_TARGET_OSARCH=arm64 -s -j4
ls: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-*: No such file or directory
ls: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-*: No such file or directory