# Path to Xcode's compiler?

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, xcode5

I have a third party tool which is configured using the compiler. The compiler I am using is the one which comes with Xcode 5.0.2. While I am aware of `xcodebuild`, I believe that command is not the compiler per se but a tool which invokes the compiler, yes? So, where can I find the actual compiler used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find arm-apple-darwin#-llvm-gcc-4.2 compiler on Xcode 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922885/how-to-find-arm-apple-darwin-llvm-gcc-4-2-compiler-on-xcode-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command to locate the compiler:

```
xcrun -find -sdk iphoneos clang
```

Note that the path could change with future Xcode releases, so you wouldn't want to hardcode the path returned by this somewhere, you would just want to use the result of this command to get the path.